# How can I get value in `combobox` with function

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, return-value

```
public string year(ComboBox cbYears)
{
    string value = null;
    value= cbYears.SelectedText;
    return value;
}
```

This is my function but i get always null value, where is my mistake can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `GetItemText` method to get the text of the selected combobox item :

```
public string year(ComboBox cbYears)
{
    return cbYears.GetItemText(cbYears.SelectedItem);
}
```

Comment: this is works for months and days i think i have some mistake in select year automatic i use this  `cbYears.SelectedText = year;`

Comment: Does my solution work for you or not? Sorry I don't understand your problem, could you post additional information or code to your question that describes your problem.

Comment: Your solution works. How can I select year automatic in load section?

Comment: Sorry I would help you with this but I don't understand your problem. Please post additional information and code to your question. Post the example where your new problem occurs

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like this:

string value = cbYears.SelectedItem.Text;
return value;

Comment: `SelectedItem` doesn't have a property called `Text`

Comment: sorry i thought it was a web app but your coding a windows forms so you go with:
string value = cbYears.GetItemText(cbYears.SelectedItem);

Answer (score 0):

I think it would work

```
 public string year(ComboBox cbYears)
    {
        var result = cbYears.SelectedItem as string;
        return result;
    }
```